# Adding elements to List using a comprehension

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Lets say I have a list:

```
List = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to use a comprehension to output a list of lists for every element, let's say `i`, in "`List`" containing `1,2,...,i`.  So the comprehension would output:

```
[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

The same would work for a `List` of `List = [1,3,5]` where the output would be:

```
[[1],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I do not want to use any modules like numpy or itertools

Any help would me much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Sure:

```
>>> [range(1, i+1) for i in List]
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Good answer. The OP is using Python 3, so I think you would need to convert the range object to a list: `list(range(1, i+1))`.